# PL/SQL: UPDATE inside CURSOR, but some data is NULL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm still learning some of the PL/SQL differences, so this may be an easy question, but... here goes.

I have a cursor which grabs a bunch of records with multiple fields. I then run two separate SELECT statements in a LOOP from the cursor results to grab some distances and calculate those distances. These work perfectly.

When I go to update the table with the new values, my problem is that there are four pieces of specific criteria.

```
update work
        set kilometers = calc_kilo,
            kilo_test = test_kilo                                  
        where lc = rm.lc
        AND ld = rm.ld
        AND le = rm.le
        AND lf = rm.lf
        AND code = rm.code
        AND lcode = rm.lcode
        and user_id = username;
```

My problem is that this rarely updating because rm.lf and rm.le have NULL values in the database. How can I combat this, and create the correct update.

Comment: Also, since I'm in a cursor, using IS NULL would require an IF statement or something, and I can't seem to get the syntax right. I suppose leaving out the statements would work, but the IF statements seem to give compiler errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want to match `lf` with `rm.lf`, including when they're both null? If that's what you want, then this will do it:

```
...
AND (lf = rm.lf 
  OR (lf IS NULL AND rm.lf IS NULL)
)
...
```

It's comparing the values of `lf` and `rm.lf`, which will return false if either is null, so the `OR` condition returns true if they're both null.

Comment: rm.lf MAY be NULL from the cursor on any pass through the loop. So, it isn't a condition. It could be lf = 10 on one pass, and on the next pass, lf = NULL.

Problem is that lf = NULL isn't valid. lf IS NULL is valid. How do I go about creating that inside the loop when the data changes constantly.

Comment: Worked... i must have had a brain fart for a minute there. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The same solution again that a lot of people use:
...
AND nvl(lf,'N/A') = nvl(rm.lf, 'N/A') 
...

nvl is a function which says "if the first parameter is not null then return it, otherwise return the second parameter".

Answer (score 1):

> I have a cursor which grabs a bunch of records with multiple fields. I then run two separate SELECT statements in a LOOP from the cursor results to grab some distances and calculate those distances. These work perfectly.
>
> When I go to update the table with the new values, my problem is that there are four pieces of specific criteria.

The first thing I'd look at is not using a cursor to read data, then make calculations, then perform updates. In 99% of cases it's faster and easier to just run updates that do all of this in a single step

Answer (score 0):

```
update work 
        set kilometers = calc_kilo, 
            kilo_test = test_kilo                                   
        where lc = rm.lc 
        AND ld = rm.ld 
        AND NVL(le,'x') = NVL(rm.le,'x') 
        AND NVL(lf,'x') = NVL(rm.lf,'x') 
        AND code = rm.code 
        AND lcode = rm.lcode 
        and user_id = username;
```